# C# WinForms How to increase number with specific format

Tags: c#, winforms, increment

I want to make increment that not starts for example from 0 to 1000 but from 0000 to 1000 how i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to to format a number as string:

```
0.ToString("D4"); // "0000"
1.ToString("D4"); // "0001"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Demo: http://ideone.com/VlYBh

Comment: Perhaps OP wants.. `for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){i.ToString("D4");}`

Comment: Yes anonymous, I know to do that part :)